# How to activate an extension when file explorer is shown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a VS Code extension that adds a status bar item when the file explorer is shown.

I can't find the proper `activationEvent` to match this requirement.

I tried

```json
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView:explorer"
  ],
```

or

```json
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView:workbench.explorer.fileView"
  ],
```

But the extension does not activate.

If I register the *star* (`*`) event or `onStartupFinished` event, however, the extension activates:

```json
  "activationEvents": [ "*" ],
```

```json
  "activationEvents": [ "onStartupFinished" ],
```

I'd like to avoid this event if possible because of documented best practices.

How can I fix my manifest?